# Active admin rails, JS not loading on changing tabs or links

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I have rails application that has Active Admin.
I added new JS(custom scripts) in the javascripts folder, gmaps scripts and s3_direct_upload scripts. Now when I go to the admin panel the first time I launch the JS are loaded, but when I change tabs on the top the JS are not loaded again. I have different JS for different tabs and other links (like new user, new category etc). I load the page and the JS are loaded when I tap on something it just changes the HTML but the JS stay the same.

Is this some configuration problem or is it because of the new scripts?
I did `assets:precompile` for `RAILS_ENV=production` because when I deploy to heroku did not work without it.

Any opinions on this? Anyone has this problem?

Comment: For me it sounds like you have a problem with turbo links

Comment: Correct, I remove it from active_admin.js.coffee and it works. Thanks.